# How to create a google map with multiple markers each with their own click through url?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create a map that has a polyline with multiple markers each with their own click through url and info windows. I've inserted the url into the marker info, but everytime I test it I receive an error message. I am hoping to add images to info windows too.- (404 Not Found)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
       height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
      </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
      // Styles a map in night mode.
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 38.6530169, lng: -90.3835485},
        zoom: 6,
        styles: [
            {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{ color: '#ebe3cd'}]},
            {elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]},
            {elementType: 'labels.text.fill',stylers: [{color: '#523735'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]},
            {
              featureType: 'administrative',
              elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{ 'visibility': 'off'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{ color: '#c9b2a6'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
          stylers: [{'visibility': 'off'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{ color: '#dcd2be'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#ae9e90'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.neighborhood',
          stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.province',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{visibility: 'on'},{weight: '1.5'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'landscape.natural',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#93817c'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'geometry.fill',
          stylers: [{ color: '#a5b076'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#447530'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'labels.icon',
          stylers: [{visibility: "off"}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.arterial',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#fdfcf8'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#f8c967'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#e9bc62'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#e98d58'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#db8555'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.local',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#806b63'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit',
          stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit.line',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit.line',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#8f7d77'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit.line',
          elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#ebe3cd'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit.station',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'geometry.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#b9d3c2'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#92998d'}]
        }
        ]
    });
     var locations = [
      ['August 20, 
1832',40.423731,-83.8944137,10,"https://www.google.com/"],
      ['September 19th, 
1832',40.4237331,-83.8944137,9,"https://www.google.com/"],
      ['September 25th, 
1832',40.1066821,-84.649707,8,"https://www.google.com/"],
      ['October 1st, 
1832',39.8379723,-84.958815,7,"https://www.google.com/"],
      ['October 10th, 
  1832',39.6415502,-86.8738581,6,"https://www.google.com/"],
      ['October 14th, 
  1832',39.6959955,-87.9244163,5,"https://www.google.com/"],
      ['October 29th, 
 1832',37.9204684,-89.9206883,4,"https://www.google.com/"],
      ['November 1, 1832', 
   37.4986755,-90.3080368,3,"https://www.google.com/"],
      ['November 28th. 
  1832',37.2035869,-92.048218,2,"https://www.google.com/"],
      ['December 14th, 1832',36.8811974, 
 -94.9064899,1,"https://www.google.com/"],

    ];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;
    var markers = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
      marker.url = locations[i][4]; 
    });

    window.location.href = marker.url;


    markers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      window.location.href = marker.url;
    });


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {

    var html = '<h4>' + locations[i][0] + '</h4>';
    html += '<img src="' + locations[i][4] + '" />';

      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
    }


    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      {lat: 40.423731, lng: -83.8944137},
      {lat: 40.4237331, lng: -83.8944137},
      {lat: 40.1066821, lng: -84.649707},
      {lat: 39.8379723, lng: -84.958815},
      {lat: 39.6415502, lng: -86.8738581},
      {lat: 39.6959955, lng: -87.9244163},
      {lat: 37.9204684, lng: -89.9206883},
      {lat: 37.4986755, lng: -90.3080368},
      {lat: 37.2035869, lng: -92.048218},
      {lat: 36.8811974, lng: -94.9064899},

      ];

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlanCoordinates,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#340684',
      strokeOpacity: .5,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
  }
</script>

<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
 key=AIzaSyBI8ub80FYP5f06rn2yxwNgJW55L3NEOlM&v=3&callback=initMap">
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the url added?

Comment: The url is under var locations:                                                                                          
                                                                                                             
var locations = [
      ['Seneca & Shawnee Assemble in Lewistown, Ohio August 1832',40.423731,-83.8944137, 3,'www.google.com'],
      ['September 20, 1832', 40.1489329, -84.3119643, 2],
      ['October 1, 1832', 39.7520154,-85.603323, 1],

Comment: But in locations array you have only one url for the first item: ['August 20,1832',40.4225179,-83.884628,10,"https://www.google.com",]
The restant items have not one url to match to locations[i][4]

Answer (score 0):

In this portion of your code, assuming you have a url defined in each array element's 4th position:

```
...
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
     map: map
});
//-----------add this : 
marker.url = locations[i][4];
...
```

Also use this when redirecting:

```
window.location.href = marker.url;
```

And you may need to define your urls with the http or https prefix.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's still not working. I've updated the code with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Locations array must seem like this:

```
var locations = [
  ['August 20,1832',40.4225179,-83.884628,10,"https://www.google.com",],
  ['September 19th, 1832',40.4237331,-83.8944136,9,"your_url_here"],
  ['September 25th, 1832',40.1066821,-84.649707,8,"your_url_here"],
  //... and so on
];
```

After that you can try adding in the for loop:

```
marker.url = locations[i][4]; ///
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. But it is still not working for me.